# Magento observer fires only in admin panel, how can I execute it also in the front end?

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

I've an observer that works well in the admin back-end, the name of the event is *checkout_submit_all_after*. When I make an order as a customer the event is not fired, maybe I miss something in the configuration file, here the config.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyFancyModuleName>
      <version>0.1.1</version>
    </MyFancyModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <events>
      <checkout_submit_all_after>
        <observers>
          <awesome>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>MyFancyModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>this_is_a_magic_function</method>
          </awesome>
        </observers>
      </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the event is fired on the front end? That does not look like an event that I have seen on the frontend before.

Without knowing what you are looking to do it looks like you may want to use the sales_order_place_before or sales_order_place_after event. (gets triggered just before or after an order is placed on the frontend)